# My Controller Not Redirecting Properly

Tags: codeigniter

On my codeigniter project I have a core/MY_Controller.php every controller extends MY_Controller.

If in my `$ignore = array()` the in_array should ignore them, but then still redirects to error page but then after that shows **Firefox error page The page isn't redirecting properly**

I am not sure why not ignoring files that are in my array?

Any suggestions thanks in advance. I have tried hooks same issue.

```
<?php 

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $files = glob(FCPATH . 'application/modules/admin/controllers/*/*.php');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $part = explode('/', dirname($file));

        $permission = end($part) . '/' . basename($file, '.php');

        $ignore = array(
            'common/Column_left',
            'common/Dashboard',
            'common/Login',
            'common/Logout',
            'common/Footer',
            'common/Header',
            'error/Permission'
        );  

        if (!in_array($permission, $ignore)) {
            redirect('admin/error/permission');
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Obviously your in_array test is always failing. Basic Debug time...So The very first thing you would have done is to check all the variables concerned. So you would have done a var_dump($files) and a var_dump($permission) to see what you are actually getting. SO do any $permission entries match what is in your $ignore array?

Comment: As you are running this each and everytime, when you do get a mismatch you will perform a redirect in an endless loop. What is that you think you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: If folder/file.php is not in that array then will get redirected to that controller. redirect('admin/error/permission');

Comment: Ok so as I asked earlier - what are you getting in the variables $files and $permission? Will you ever get a Match?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the content inside if to

```
redirect('admin/error/permission'); exit;
```

just add a exit.